# Vue 2.0 Component - could not render all <div>s within a template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am composing a modal component as I learn VueJS. The modal component basically consists of two major elements: the actual box containing all contents and an overlay.

Now the problem I am stuck in is the overlay element is not rendered at all. But if I moved the overlay from the component template to parent scope, everything would be alright.

Here is the code of parent scope:

```
<my-modal v-show="show" v-on:hide="show = false"></my-modal>
<!-- Overlay will be rendered properly if I put overlay here. -->
<!-- <div class="my-modal-overlay" v-show="show" @click="show = false"></div>  -->
```

And the code of component template:

```
<template id="tpl-my-modal">
    <transition name="modal-fade" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
            <div class="my-modal-box">
                <div class="my-modal-content">
                    <div class="my-modal-header"><h1>Title</h1></div>
                    <div class="my-modal-body">Body</div>
                    <div class="my-modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('hide')">Close</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Overlay is not rendered at all if I put it here. -->
            <div class="my-modal-overlay" @click="show = false"></div>
        </transition>
    </template>
```

The Javascript:

```
Vue.component('my-modal', {
    template: '#tpl-my-modal'
})
```

Two screenshots. The grey layer is the overlay element which covers all the viewport.

[image]

[image]

Could anyone shed some light upon the problem? Thank you!

---

Update:

Here come the [snippets](https://jsfiddle.net/9x8y7dvx/). Feel free to comment/comment out line 11 / line 26 in HTML to see the difference.

---

Update:

It turns out that a Vue Component can have no more than one root element, and `<transition>` tag can only have a single element, which means what I did before was wrong.

Thus I tweaked the code a bit, and now in the console Vue does not complain any more. And both modal box and overlay are rendered.

```
<template id="tpl-my-modal">
    <div>
      <transition name="modal-fade" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
        <div class="my-modal-box">
          <div class="my-modal-content">
            <div class="my-modal-header">
              <h1>{{ program.title }}</h1></div>
            <div class="my-modal-body"> {{ program.intro }}</div>
            <div class="my-modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('hide')">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
      <div class="my-modal-overlay" @click="show = false"></div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

But one problem is unsolved: all transitions are gone. Here are the [snippets](https://jsfiddle.net/9x8y7dvx/4/). What is the problem?

Comment: I think it kind of make sense that the overlay will appear if it's in the parent component, you what can you do is when the modal is opened, you toggle a class with your overlay on the parent.

Comment: @flyingSmurfs I think a parent component doesn't really care what is inside a modal component. Think about reusability: if there are 100 parent components are going to use this modal component, they have to define a overlay in their own template (as programmer we have to copy and paste 100 times), which definitely is not cool, right? That's why originally I put it in the child component template. But somehow Vue just doesn't render the overlay.

Comment: wrap the model div and the overlay div inside another div [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x8y7dvx/1/).

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN thank you. But the behaviour/animation becomes kinda weird if you wrap the modal box and overlay, isn't it? Not quite users might expect, right? lol.

Answer (score 1):

For the transition problem, you should put the `transition` tag right after the root `div` of your template like this..

```
<template id="tpl-my-modal">
<transition name="modal-fade" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
    <div>
    //the rest of your code..
```

because `v-show` will be applied to the root `div` when you use it to the component `my-modal`

```
<my-modal v-show="show" v-on:hide="show = false" v-bind:program="activeProgram"></my-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cihkem/0rmt28y2/

```js
Vue.component('my-modal', {
  template: '#tpl-my-modal',
  props: ['program', 'show']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false,
    activeProgram: {},
    programs: [{
      title: 'Westworld',
      intro: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi cum incidunt ipsum impedit nostrum, repellendus illum, officia labore neque ea quam ad maiores corporis deserunt quos odio distinctio similique in.'
    }, {
      title: 'Game of Thrones',
      intro: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet perspiciatis eos aperiam, veritatis, voluptate eius similique saepe libero consectetur suscipit dolorem molestiae animi nostrum voluptatem quidem sapiente? Fugit, hic, fugiat!'
    }, {
      title: 'X Files',
      intro: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit nobis, nisi ex exercitationem magnam nemo repudiandae dolor maxime odio reprehenderit animi ducimus a consequatur, saepe suscipit dolorem ratione tempore perferendis.'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    showDetails: function(program) {
      this.show = true;
      this.activeProgram = program;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .3;
}

.my-modal-box {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
}

.my-modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1050;
}

.my-modal-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.my-modal-body,
.my-modal-footer {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.my-modal-header,
.my-modal-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.my-modal-footer {
  text-align: right;
}

.program-list-item {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="app">
      <ol>
        <li v-for="program in programs" class="program-list-item">
          {{ program.title}}
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="showDetails(program)">Details</button>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <my-modal :show="show" v-on:hide="show = false" v-bind:program="activeProgram"></my-modal>
      <!--  <div class="my-modal-overlay" v-show="show" @click="show = false"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <template id="tpl-my-modal">
    <div>
      <transition enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
        <div v-show="show" class="my-modal-box" key="modal">
          <div class="my-modal-content">
            <div class="my-modal-header">
              <h1>{{ program.title }}</h1></div>
            <div class="my-modal-body"> {{ program.intro }}</div>
            <div class="my-modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="$emit('hide')">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>         
      </transition>     
      <div v-show="show" class="my-modal-overlay" @click="show = false" key="overlay"></div>
    </div>
  </template>
</body>
```

Is it what you need?